# In net core, is it accepted for a controller to have a two words name, such as "UserAccessController"?

Tags: c#, .net-core

We have a project using net core. And my boss just told me that we will have another module called "User Access". So the first thing came to my mind is the controller for it. Can I name it UserAccessController or UseraccessController?

I just think it's weird to name a Controller with two CapitalLetter/CamelCase. Or i'm just used to one word controller like UserController, ReportController, etc.

My question is, is it ethical for developers to name a controller with two CamelCase? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Poor use of the word ["ethical"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ethical).

Comment: Why would it be unethical?  Insensitive to camels?

Comment: Maybe you mean is it "Industry Standard"? I guess you have to consider the alternative, you'd end up with some horrible controller names if you didn't allow multiple word names.

Comment: @user2.. I know it's just I forgot the right word for it sorry.

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow, It's just I haven't seen a TwoWordController ever and so I wonder that's all.

Comment: This is just a matter of opinion. :) There is no technical reason (or even practical reason) why you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is acceptable, as long as the two (or more) words describe a noun.

```
class UserAccessController : Controller  { }
class AccessHistoryController : Controller { }
class MailingAddressController : Controller { }
```

In your case, "Access" is being used as a noun and not a verb, so it's OK.

What is less acceptable is when the name contains a verb. The verb aspect should be a method name and kept out of the controller name.

```
//Bad
class DeleteUserController : Controller { }

//Better
class UserController : Controller 
{
    public async ActionResult Delete(UserDto user) { }
}
```

See [Microsoft naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces), which say, among other things:

> **Names of Classes, Structs, and Interfaces**
>
> The naming guidelines that follow apply to general type naming.
>
> ✓ DO name classes and structs with nouns or noun phrases, using PascalCasing.
>
> This distinguishes type names from methods, which are named with verb phrases.

Comment: I downvoted this because you answered a Oinion based question, rather then flagging it.

Comment: @Christopher Except it is not *really* a lone opinion, especially as answered 1) distinction of Nouns vs Verbs to avoid confusion; and 2) defacto .NET/Microsoft Naming Conventions (there are variations 'accepted' here, such as acronym cases and variations of non-public members, etc., but generally not for CapWordsForTypesIncludingControllers);